# Cosine and sine dense in unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

We may assume the following theorem:

> **Theorem**: A real number $\lambda$ is irrational iff the set $\{m+\lambda n\mid m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Assume $\lambda$ is irrational. How can we show that the set $\{(\cos(2\pi n\lambda), (\sin(2\pi n\lambda))\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$?

Comment: What can you throw at it? If you have the ammunition, you can say that the set is an infinite subgroup of the unit circle, hence so is its closure. A closed subgroup of the unit circle is either finite or the entire circle. If you don't have that, you essentially prove the above without having the terminology at your disposal.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't think I have that -- is it hard to prove? The notes I'm reading gives the theorem I posted as a hint, so I thought it should be used somehow. But I can't see how.

Comment: Ah, somehow I missed the theorem ;) Using that, it is not hard to prove. Consider the map $x \mapsto (\cos (2\pi x), \sin (2\pi x))$. You know (I expect) that is continuous and surjective. How is the set $\{ (\cos (2\pi n\lambda),\sin(2\pi n\lambda)) : n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ related to the set in the theorem?

Comment: How about this: you can maybe show that the set {$(2\pi n\gamma)$} is dense in $[-1,1]$ , and then use the fact that $( \sint,cost) is a parametrization of the circle?

Comment: @DanielFischer It is the image of the set in the theorem under your map. This means it is the image of a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Since the map is continuous and surjective, the image must also be dense in the circle. Wait.. or is it? Need to think a bit..

Comment: Right. And now you can use that for any continuous map $f$ and any $A$ in its domain, you have $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$.

Comment: Yes, I think I get it now. Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By, e.g., the equidistribution theorem, we have that the set {$n\lambda$} is dense in $[0,1]$ ( in $\mathbb R$ , actually). This means for every t in $[0,1]$, there is a sequence {$t_n$} with {$t_n \rightarrow t$}. Now, the parametrization $(\cos2\pi t, \sin2\pi t)$ is continuous, and uniformly-continuous in $[0,1]$ (by compactness of $[0,1]$), so that it takes Cauchy sequences in $[0,1]$ to Cauchy sequences in $S^1$ ( and, by completeness--from compactness-- of $S^1$), these sequences converge to the point $(\cos t, \sin t)$.